# Tcolorbox without a toprule

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

Using tcolorbox I want to create a box that has now inner `toprule`. With the options below, there is still a line visible. Also the body block clashes with the frame. Do you know how to fix that?

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}\tcbuselibrary{skins}     
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=black,
    arc=15mm,
    toptitle=5mm,
    /tcb/boxrule=.5mm,
    /tcb/titlerule=0mm,
    titlerule style={white,line width=0mm}, % tikz arguments
    left=10mm,right=10mm,top=0mm,bottom=10mm,
    title={\strut#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]  
            \begin{column}{\textwidth}
                \begin{mybox}[Test]
                    \lipsum[31]
                \end{mybox}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You've set `arc=15mm`. The value of `toptitle` should at least be half of it, thus I've changed it to `toptitle=10mm`.
2. If you set `line width=0mm` in the `titlerule style`, though I don't know the reason, there might be a very slight gray line (depending on your pdf reader). My experience is that in this case you can set it to a small positive value, say `0.1mm`, and the line shall be truly invisible. Another way might be to replace `enhanced` with `enhanced jigsaw`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    enhanced jigsaw, % use this the slight gray line will be removed
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=black,
    arc=15mm,
    toptitle=10mm,
    boxrule=.5mm,
    titlerule=0mm,
    titlerule style={white,line width=.1mm}, 
    left=10mm,right=10mm,top=0mm,bottom=10mm,
    title={\strut#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
            \begin{column}{\textwidth}
                \begin{mybox}[Test]
                    \lipsum[31]
                \end{mybox}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! Setting the line width to very small value indeed removes the line when zooming in. However, the line is still visible when not zooming in. I tried to do the same approach with the "titlerule" argument. Unfortunately, that does not do the trick.

Comment: @Nailuj use `enhanced jigsaw` solve the problem

Comment: @Nailuj Actually my first idea was to use `enhanced jigsaw`, but then on my side I can still see the slight gray line so I changed to use the `.1mm` method. I just received an edit suggested by @Tom for using `enhanced jigsaw`, kept it in case this works for you.

Comment: The `enhanced jigsaw` option seems to do the trick! Thanks @Jinwen @Tom